# Insert multiple values to same Key in JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array like 
`electronics = ["radio","Tv"]`

i have to create an object like 
`{ "Ids":"radio:Tv", "type":"electronics" }`

How to achieve this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure y this is given -1?? any issue with the question i asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** here

```js
var electronics = ["radio", "Tv"];

var res = {
  Ids: electronics.join(':'),
  type: 'electronics'
};
console.log(res);
```